# Python actor model: thespian vs pykka

Tags: python, asynchronous, actor-model, pykka

I want to play around with actors in python. Apparently, the two most popular alternatives are [thespian](https://thespianpy.com/doc/) and [pykka](https://www.pykka.org/en/latest/api/). I'm looking for something actively developed and easy to use.

Which would you recommend and why?

Comment: Unless you are asking for a very specific technical difference the choice of two different libraries is an opinion based question and off-topic on SO.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. I'm interested in a comparison between the two libraries, could you please suggest any edits to make the question not OT?

Answer (score 4):

I'm have used pykka in the past a few times and here is my take:

`pykka` is simple lean and elegant, if you only need Threads/Greenlets its a fine choice

`thespian` looks a bit more complex but does support multi-proc and clustering so if you need those, it's your match